Move function defined in React component into external file
I have a React component that contains functionality to query TV shows from an external API, add shows to be tracked and track them. In the component, I have many functions defined to handle input changes, form submissions, setting various state variables, etc.
At this point, the component JSX file is getting very long, so I would like to move the individual functions I've defined into an external file, export them from that external file, and then import them all back in at the top of the component JSX file for use within the component.
For example, here is one function with my React component:
export default function Tracker(){
    const [show, setShow] = useState('');
    const handleShowChange = name => (e) =>{
        setShow(e.target.value);
    };
    return(
        <>
            ... 
                <AddShowForm
                    showData={showData}
                    handleShowChange={handleShowChange}
                    handleShowSubmit={handleShowSubmit}
                    handleAddedShowSubmit={handleAddedShowSubmit}/>
            ...         
        </>
    );
};

I tried moving handleShowChange out of the React component Tracker.jsx and into an external file TrackerFunctions.js, then importing it back in, however when I search for a show on that page, when the handleShowChange function is called, I get an error in my browser's console stating "Uncaught ReferenceError: setShow is not defined".
I've tried importing the React component Tracker into TrackerFunctions.js, hoping that would give the handleShowChange function access to `setShow, but it had no effect.
I've tried exporting setShow from Tracker.jsx and into TrackerFunctions.js, however exports are only valid at the top level of a React component, and setShow doesn't exist at the top level.
I've tried passing in setShow to the AddShowForm with handleShowChange={handleShowChange(setShow)}, but I get an error in my browser's console stating "Uncaught TypeError: can't access property 'setShow' of undefined".
I've read through multiple StackExchange questions and answers with similar keywords, but can't find any posts that seem to be addressing the situation I'm encountering.
What is the correct way to set this up so I can clean up my React Tracker component and import the many necessary functions into the component?

You can create custom hooks to separate parts of your logic.

Thank you, @Arkellys! Just to confirm, is this the correct doc I should read through to figure out making a custom hook for my use case? https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks
